# Django jsonfield persisting old object values in a loop

Tags: python, django

Here is the model:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field3 = JSONField(default=[])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Below print should be None
        # But it shows the value of the previously created object, why ?
        print "------------------------------------------------"
        print self.id
        print "self.field3"
        print self.field3
        self.field2 = self.field1 + " world"
        self.field3.append(self.field2)
        super(ModelA, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is the view:

```
def view1(request):
    for x in range(1, 3):
          a = ModelA.objects.create(field1="hello%s" % x)
```

Expected output:

```
# None
# self.field3
# []

# None
# self.field3
# []
```

Achieved output:

```
# None
# self.field3
# []

# None
# self.field3
# [u'Hello1 world']

# None
# self.field3
# [u'Hello1 world', u'Hello2 world']
```

So, as per the given output, can you tell me why its using previous objects values while creating a new object ?

Comment: `self.field2 = self.field1 + " world"` Why do you expect `[]` ?

Comment: Code changed please check. Its not happening for normal fields. Its happening for JSONFields (postgres json fields)

Comment: Got it. Changing default from [] to list (that is default=list) makes it work :)

Comment: Really good question by the way! First time I see a thread on that. Hope my post helps.

Answer (score 3):

This is from Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/):

> If you give the field a default, ensure it’s a callable such as dict
>   (for an empty default) or a callable that returns a dict (such as a
>   function). Incorrectly using default={} creates a mutable default that
>   is shared between all instances of JSONField.

Therefore use this instead:

```
field3 = JSONField(default=list)
```

Comment: You need to provide the callable, not the result of the callable, otherwise you end up with the same problem. Also OP needs a list. So `JSONField(default=list)`.

Comment: Updated my answer. Since he needed a list. You're right. Thank you